# Putting Jsoup abs:href results into an array and looping through the array

Tags: java, html, arrays, arraylist, jsoup

I am having some trouble understanding how to properly add to an array. What I am trying to accomplish is adding the results from the a method into an array and then run through the array.

Here is an example of what I need, or assume I need:

array{"websiteaddress","websiteaddress","websiteaddress","websiteaddress","websiteaddress"}

but instead I'm getting:
websiteaddress
websiteaddress
websiteaddress
websiteaddress
websiteaddress
websiteaddress

Here is the code I am working with:

```
private static final String webSiteURL = "https://websitename.com/";

    //The path of the folder that you want to save the images to
    private static final String folderPath = "C://path/";

    private static final ArrayList<String> webPages = new ArrayList<>();

    public static String[] thisIsAStringArray = {"https://websitename.com/"};    
    public static String[] tempArray = new String[ thisIsAStringArray.length + 1 ];


    /**
     * 
     * Method description: 
     * Date: Mar 17, 2018
     * @param args
     * @return void
     */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                String path = folderPath + getPageTitle(webSiteURL).replaceAll(" ", "-");




                pageLinks(webSiteURL);

                System.out.println(thisIsAStringArray);

                for(String web : thisIsAStringArray)
                {

                        for(int n = 0; n < thisIsAStringArray.length - 1; n++)
                    {

                        System.out.println(thisIsAStringArray[n]);
                        getPageTitle(web);

                        pageLinks(web);

                        creatDirectory(folderPath, getPageTitle(web));      
                        getsImagesAndSaves(path, web);
                        n++;

                    }
                }
            }

            /**
             * 
             * Method description: Get all the links on the page and put them into an array
             * Date: Mar 16, 2018
             * @param src
             * @return void
             */
            public static void pageLinks(String src)
            {
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL(src);
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3*1000);
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
                    for (Element link : links) 
                    {

                        System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
                        String noHref = link.attr("abs:href");

                        for(int i = 0; i < thisIsAStringArray.length; i++)
                        {
                            tempArray[i] = thisIsAStringArray[i];

                        }
                        //thisIsAStringArray[i] = noHref;
                        tempArray[thisIsAStringArray.length] = noHref;

                    }

                    thisIsAStringArray = tempArray;


                }
                catch(Exception error)
                {
                    System.out.println(error + " Something went wrong getting the links!");
                }
            }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 arrays: `thisIsAStringArray` with size 1 and `tempArray` with size 2. Their size is fixed and cannot be changed! Now you have a loop:

```
for (Element link : links) 
{
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < thisIsAStringArray.length; i++)
    {
        tempArray[i] = thisIsAStringArray[i];
    }
}
```

which reads - for each link you've found, `i` loops from zero to one (which means that inside the inner loop `i` will have only the value 0) and than adds the link to the first place (with index 0).
You cannot change the size of an array in runtime. If you cannot tell ahead how many items you will have, you must use a `List`. Try something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element link : links)
    myList.add(link);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Worked great!  YOU ARE AWESOME!